# How to expand aira-expanded box to select values?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am messing around with META and want to expand an input box via the aria-expanded element, so I can discover the list of values after expanding the input box.

The example HTML from META is given as follows:

```
<input class="_58al" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="js_cxx" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="false" role="combobox" placeholder="Typing IDs to select Custom Audiences" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" type="text" value="" tabindex="0" data-auto-logging-id="fffa139c9e7dc" xpath="1">
```

I have tried the  following:

```
$("input[placeholder='Typing IDs to select Custom Audiences']").on('click', function(){
    var hidden = $('[aria-expanded="false"]').hasClass('hidden');
    $('[aria-expanded="false"]').attr('aria-expanded', 'true').removeClass('hidden')
})
```

How do I get this to expanded in chrome developer when using javascript?